# How to get host header on which site collection is being hosted?

Tags: site-collection, host-header

For example my site collections structure is as follows:

http://testserver1.com/sites/sitecollection1

http://testserver1.com/sites/sitecollection2

http://testserver1.com/sitecollection3

http://testserver1.com/team/sitecollection4

I want to get http://testserver1.com (host header) from the code? how can I do it using object model? Is there a problem if we have Alternate access mapping being configured on these site collections as well?

Comment: Both answers bellow are good.. Depends on whether the current context means anything or not in your situation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SPContext.Current.Site.HostName` property to get the host name?

Normally you can use `SPContext.Current.Site.Url` to return the Url of the root website in the site collection for the current web request.  If you want the context of the current web site then use `SPContext.Current.Web.Url.`

Answer (score 3):

When you say "host header," I assume you are referring to the web application to which your site collections belong. With that in mind, you can use the SPWebApplication's **AlternateUrls** collection to get the host header(s) associated with that web application.

Since it is possible to have multiple URLs associated with a single web application, you would need to iterate through this collection to get/find the host header you want. For instance:

```
SPAlternateUrlCollection allUrls = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.AlternateUrls;
foreach (SPAlternateUrl url in allUrls)
{
    // Do something with each url.Uri.ToString()
}
```

Note that you will need to add a reference to **Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration** to make use of this code.